# Transfer data from one device to another without storing it in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, local-storage, video-streaming

I have a situation where there is a video file stored in the secondary storage of one device (desktop) and that video is to be streamed on another device (mobile/desktop). Is there a way that I can connect these two devices and transfer the video file without storing it on my node.js server?
And if storing is must, then is there a way that I can continuously overwrite the same chunk (few bytes) of video in the server? Any other better alternates are welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an app where i need to pass files from the mobile to the PC. And the best solution for me is WebRTC or P2P